# debian Linux QinQ (vlan stacking)

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vlan

I am trying to create stacked VLAN interface on a debian 10 server. Here is what I have placed in the /etc/network/interfaces:

```
iface enp34s0.300 inet manual
        address 0.0.0.0
        netmask 0.0.0.0

auto enp34s0.300.1239
iface enp34s0.300.1239 inet static
        address X.X.X.X
        netmask X.X.X.X
```

The first interface is going UP without any problem:

```
:~# ifup enp34s0.300
```

But the second one is failing :

```
:~# ifup enp34s0.300.1239
Error: argument "enp34s0.300.1239" is wrong: "name" not a valid ifname
ifup: ignoring unknown interface enp34s0.300.1239=enp34s0.300.1239
```

I have the vlan packet installed:

```
:~# dpkg -l | grep vlan
ii  vlan                                 2.0.5                        all          ifupdown integration for vlan configuration
```

```
:~# lsmod | grep 802
8021q                  40960  0
garp                   16384  1 8021q
mrp                    20480  1 8021q
```

Do you have any idea what is going wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: We have found the solution, there is a limitation to the interface name length to 16 characters: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=240607

Comment: You should write an answer to the question, but not just with the link but for example what you actually did to get it working.